# Grunt Concurrent cannot run too many tasks

Tags: concurrency, gruntjs

I'm trying to run multiple watch tasks with grunt, but it seems to not be able to. I'm using grunt concurrent, but it seems to only run a portion of the tasks I specify, stopping just short.

Here is the snippet of my gruntfile:

```
concurrent:
  compile:
    tasks: ["watch:app", "watch:html", "watch:images", "watch:lib", "watch:server"]
    options:
      logConcurrentOutput: true
```

When I run this, the output shows:

```
Running "concurrent:compile" (concurrent) task
Running "watch:images" (watch) task
Waiting...Running "watch:app" (watch) task
Waiting...Running "watch:html" (watch) task
Waiting...Running "watch:lib" (watch) task
Waiting...
```

For some reason, it's skipping my server task completely. I initially thought the server tasks was not setup correctly, but I can remove a watch task, and it will correctly run the server task along with the other 3, it just cannot run all 5 at once.

Am I implementing this inappropriately?

Comment: Is that necessary? By default the watch task will watch all targets already.

Answer (score 11):

So from the documentation, simply declare the amount of tasks you want. so in your case:

```
options:
      logConcurrentOutput: true
      limit: 5
```

By default it just uses how many cores your CPU has..

> limit
>
> Type: Number Default: Number of CPU cores
>   (require('os').cpus().length) with a minimum of 2
>
> Limit of how many tasks that are run concurrently.

https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent

Comment: Maybe it has changed since January but by default it uses twice the cores number you have.